Can a dominance frontier not exist?
Let's consider the main example of the Dominator article of wikipedia:

And let's consider the following definitions taken from the same article:


A node d strictly dominates a node n if d dominates n and d does not equal n.

The dominance frontier of a node d is the set of all nodes ni such that d dominates an immediate predecessor of ni, but d does not
strictly dominate ni. It is the set of nodes where d's dominance
stops.



What is the dominance frontier of node 1?
My understanding is that it is undefined simply because node 1 strictly dominates 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 - which remove them all from consideration because of the last part of the dominance frontier definition "and d does not strictly dominate ni".
This also applies to the dominance frontier of node 2.
Is it expected that there is no dominance frontier for these nodes?

A set can be well-defined, but contain no elements; in that case it's known as the empty set.
The dominance frontier of a node d is always well-defined, in that it's always possible to determine whether a given node is in the dominance frontier of d. If no nodes are in that set, so be it!

That makes sense. I guess I find very strange that neither node 1 or node 2 have a dominance frontier considering that we need one to, for example, know where a phi function is needed when generating an SSA form.

@EricMORAND: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood this answer. Both node 1 and node 2 have dominance frontiers. It's just that both dominance frontiers are empty (i.e., contain no nodes). You can absolutely use that in determining where a Φ function is needed, it's just that for some variable assignments, a Φ function is needed in zero places. [continued]

[continued] For example, take the example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form#Converting_to_SSA. The only node that assigns to x is the top node, whose dominance frontier contains no nodes; therefore, no nodes need a Φ function for x. As the article puts it, "A Φ function for x is not needed: only one version of x, namely x₂ is reaching this place, so there is no problem".
